# S3Trigger : How to check if an image is valid?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I am creating an application using amplify. To upload images, I use the following code

```
await Storage.put(`post/${file.name}`, file, { level: "protected", contentType: file.type });
```

My code works very well, and I have no bugs.
However, I would like to verify that the files that have been uploaded are indeed images.

For that, Amplify created a lambda trigger with this code:

```
exports.handler = async function (event) {
  console.log('Received S3 event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
  const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  const key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
  console.log(`Bucket: ${bucket}`, `Key: ${key}`);
};
```

I think the answer is:

```
var params = {
  Bucket: event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name, 
  Delete: { 
    Objects: [ 
      {
        Key: event.Records[0].s3.object.key 
      }
    ]
  }
};

s3.deleteObjects(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Question 1: How can I check the mime type of file?

Question 2: How can I create an image thumbnail?

Comment: You have two separate questions. They need to be in two separate posts. SO is a **question and answer** site. Note that **question** is singular, not plural. You may want to review the [help] pages to refresh your understanding of how the site works.

Comment: Are you wanting the `Content-Type` associated with the Amazon S3 object, or are you wanting to actually examine the content of the file to determine the "mime type"?

Comment: To create a thumbnail, you would either need to write your own code (there are [examples on the Internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=s3+lambda+create+thumbnail)), or you could use a third-party service such as [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) and [Imgix](http://imgix.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
@JohnRotenstein: I want to actually examine the content of the file to determine the "mime type" to be sure that the file is indeed an image (or other type that I want).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein about the thumbnail thank you so much, I will check.

Comment: You should be able to use something like: [file-type - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type)